# How to display loading image/div on the top or instead of content div?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content-loading"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

and the following css:

```
.container {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 627px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    background: #F7F7F7;
    border: 1px solid #A3B6C9;
    padding:1px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 167px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 460px;
    float: right;
}

.content-loading  { 
  background: white url('/images/loadingIndicator_2.gif') center center no-repeat; 
}
```

I need to display that image (`loadingIndicator_2.gif`) in the center of `content` div, when ajax is loading:

```
  $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(){
          $( ".content-loading" ).show();                      
      },
      complete: function(){
          $( ".content-loading" ).hide();
      }                  
  });
```

But the image is not centred. Looks like I need to choose some other approach (probably, not use `content-loading` div?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add to the css class `.content-loading`

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/cK9C8/2/).

=== UPDATE ===

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/cK9C8/4/) the `.content-loading` is over the `.container`.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/cK9C8/5/) only over the `.content`.

If you want to see the content too, replace the `white` with `transparent`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommending using separate tags instead of just "background:"

try:

```
background-color: white;
background-image: url('/images/loadingIndicator_2.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center;
```

If that doesn't work, put your code in jsfiddle and I'll help you out some more.

Note that background-attachment: fixed; is required for the position to properly work in Opera and Firefox.

Comment: I've added code (a little bit modified) to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/LM5zp/.

Answer (score 1):

Use [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/).

Sample code:

```
var opts = {
  lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
  length: 20, // The length of each line
  width: 10, // The line thickness
  radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
  corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
  rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
  direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
  color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
  speed: 1, // Rounds per second
  trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
  shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
  hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
  className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
  zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
  top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
  left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
};

var target = document.getElementById('foo'); //put your target here!
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

Only requires [1 tiny js file](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/spin.min.js). No images

To turn it off:

```
spinner.stop();
```